# Borland C++ localization

Tags: c++, localization, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-2007

I am currently using Codegear RAD Studio 2007. One of my company clients' decided that he would be interested in localized version of our software (to Russian - I don't know if it matters, that we won't be able to use standard windows code page). As a part of our software we are using RAVE to generate some reports.

Is there any solution, that would work out-of-the-box? We are looking for a way that would make it as automatic as possible. There is huge amount of code, and not much time ;) We have forged some ideas how to make it from scratch, but they seem very time-consuming.

Personally, I have used QT for some time, but unfortunately switching to another framework is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your particulars, but generally the `gettext` library is the right way to go about internationalization and [googling for `gettext borland c++`](http://www.google.de/search?q=gettext+borland+c%2B%2B) does yield some results.

Comment: Looks good, library similar to solution provided in QT. Still, maybe some VCL dedicated solution will emerge. It would allow us to incorporate localization of RAVE reports and programs itself into one.

Comment: IIRC qt translation machinery doesn't attempt solving the plural problem (it doesn't affect all languages, but it *does* affect Russian). Just a sidenote, as it has nothing to do with VCL-centric solution ;-) It is my experience, though, that, although there are many alternatives to gettext, none of them takes translation-specific issues seriously enough, they're more technical quirks for separating strings, than linguistic-aware solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure about QT capabilities, but plural forms is not the only translation problem. I'm native speaker of language containing declension and conjugation, so I am personally aware of linguistic solutions ;) Hopefully, in our application we are not using concatenation to produce strings, so this problem is not going to show up (at least I hope so).

Comment: Of course it's not the only problem, but it's way easier to approach than declension and conjugation and therefore any translation machinery that doesn't even try to tackle the issue makes me suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, C++Builder 2009 and later have built-in tools for localization.